# ionic2 .. how to resolve promise before page load

Tags: angular, ionic2

When my user navigates to group-management page I currently fetch the groups in a http call in the constructor:

```
@Page({ ..})
export class GroupManager {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
     this._http.get(someurl)
          .map(..)
          .subscribe(..)
  }

}
```

So my requirement is: fetch the groups from the server everytime the user navigates to the group-management page.

What I would like to achieve is to not display an empty page while the groups are being fetched (and not make http call in the contructor).

Cany anyone advise on a better way of achieving this in ionic2 ?

Comment: I've posted an answer but I'm not sure which version of Ionic 2 are you using... If you're not using `Ionic2-beta.11` please let me know and I will update the answer with your Ionic2 version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch the data from the server **everytime the user navigates to the page**, the `constructor` is not the right place to do it. Instead of doing it there, we could use the `ionViewWillEnter` event.

Unfortunately, we can't control how long will the data take to be ready, but what we can do is to let the user be aware of this by showing him/her a loading message. That way, we're going to avoid showing an empty page while the data is being fetched, and also, the page will be disabled (so the user won't be able to interact with it) until the data is ready.

In `Ionic2-beta.11` you could do something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"page1.html"
})
export class Page1 {

  private loading : any;

  constructor(private _http: Http, private _loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {

    this.loading = this._loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Fetching groups...'
    });

    loading.present();

    this._http.get(someurl)
      .map(..)
      .subscribe((data) => {

        // ...

        // Hide the message when the data is ready
        this.loading.dismiss();

      });

  }

}
```